# int variables being concatenated instead of added inside System.out.println()

Tags: java, string

Why are `total_amount` and `tax_amount` concatenated together as strings instead of added together as numbers in the below `println` statement?

```
public class Test{

  int total_amount,tax_amount;
  public void cal(int total_amount,int tax_amount)
 {
     System.out.println("Total amount : "+total_amount+tax_amount);
 }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  new Test().cal(100, 20);
  }

}

Output Total amount : 10020
Expected Total amount : 120
```

Comment: Use braces for total_amount and tax_amount

Comment: It's certainly I dup so I'll just say, when it starts as a string, you have a string.

Comment: Although, the problem is typo, I upvote for [mcve]

Comment: @xenteros: I don't think it counts as a typo... just because it can be fixed in a few characters doesn't mean those characters are known to the OP. I think operator precedence is rather more than a typo issue :) But yes, having a MCVE is great.

Comment: @JonSkeet it's very rare nowadays...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's because of operator precedence. Basically, your code is doing the equivalent of:

```
System.out.println(("Total amount : " + total_amount) + tax_amount);
```

So when `total_amount` is 100, and `tax_amount` is 20, that ends up being:

```
System.out.println(("Total amount : " + 100) + 20);
```

which is evaluated as:

```
System.out.println("Total amount : 100" + 20);
```

which is evaluated as:

```
System.out.println("Total amount : 10020");
```

Options:

- Use parentheses to show how you want the operations to be grouped:

  ```
  System.out.println("Total amount : " + (total_amount + tax_amount));
  ```
- Perform the summation first, and store it in a new variable:

  ```
  int totalIncludingTax = total_amount + tax_amount;
  System.out.println("Total amount : " + totalIncludingTax);
  ```

As a side note, I'd recommend:

- Following Java naming conventions, using camelCase instead of `underscores_separating_words`, e.g. `taxAmount` instead of `tax_amount`
- Naming variables more carefully - it's odd to have a variable called `total_amount` but then print something *different* with a label of `Total amount`
- Using a static method here, as you're not actually using the fields in your object. (Those fields are confusing, as you're not using them.)

With code formatting as well, you'd end up with:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        calculateTotal(100, 20);
    }

    private static void calculateTotal(int preTaxTotal, int tax) {
        int totalIncludingTax = preTaxTotal + tax;
        System.out.println("Total amount: " + totalIncludingTax);
    }
}
```

(You should also consider what you're going to do for non-integer prices... I'd recommend either using integers, but make that the number of cents/pennies/whatever, or using `BigDeciml` to represent prices.)

Answer (score 3):

Java assumes that you want to concatenate the values as strings. You can prevent this by using brackets:

```java
System.out.println("Total amount : "+ (total_amount + tax_amount));
```

Adding the brackets makes the two values be added before concatenating the result of the addition and the `"Total amount :"` string.

Comment: I've usually seen "braces" used to mean "{" and "}". The word "brackets" can be ambiguous but is usually used to mean "(" and ")"; the word "parentheses" is unambiguously what you mean here, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet I guess you are right. Non-native English speaker here, I had to look it up. Edit incoming.

Answer (score 2):

Doing this

```
System.out.println("Total amount : "+total_amount+tax_amount);
```

is the same as printing

the concatenation of **total_amount** and **tax_amount** after the string literal **Total amount :**

so no math operation is done there

total_amount is holding the value 100 and 
tax_amount 20 therefore the output **10020**

do instead

```
 System.out.println("Total amount : " + (total_amount + tax_amount));
```